# Ubuntu client cannot connect to ubuntu server since update but windows client can

Tags: server, ssh, authentication, openssh

I'm the administrator of 3 small ubuntu servers used in our scientific group and I have ubuntu 18.04 on my personal laptop.
For the past two weeks I've been unable to access the servers remotely (I'm pretty sure this occurred after an update on the servers), but other clients using Windows (Putty and WinSCP) still have normal access. I can log into the server on site but when I try remotely those are the error messages I get:

**On the client side (ssh -vvv hostname): (I replaced the actual server name by "hostname", the IP address by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, and my username by username). I can provide the full output if needed (couldn't submit just now as the text editor here say "This looks like spam").**

- debug1: Connecting to hostname [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
- debug1: Connection established.
- ... and at the end ...
- debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
  sysadmin@hostname: Permission denied (publickey).

**I'm somehow denied access although it shows on the 9th line of debug that the connection is established. Any idea what the issue could be?**